# Do soy beans and corn flakes decrease libido?

Tags: nutrition

I have found several articles, claiming that soy beans and corn flakes have the effect of decreasing libido.

- [M Lai's HowTo-Howto Blog](http://howto-howto.blogspot.com/2011/01/foods-that-can-decrease-sexual-desire.html)

  > Soy is very good for your health. However, if consumed too much the same effect as licorice, namely reducing the levels of testosterone.
  >   [...]
  >    Kellogg created cornflakes to reduce sexual desires of the patient.
- [11 Points](http://www.11points.com/Food-Drink/11_Foods_That_Just_Might_Kill_Your_Sex_Drive) makes similar claims.

These are not high-quality sources. Are they right?

Comment: Related?  http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/is-soy-bad-for-you?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a broad research on google scholar. Here what I found:

2007 - http://ukpmc.ac.uk/abstract/MED/17710586/reload=0;jsessionid=s7Pe14OVZjNyJ6YYgcN5.0

> Short-term increased soybean intake does not affect sex hormone status, but improves spatial cognitive performance in young healthy men.

2011 - http://www.neptjournal.com/NEPT10(3)Full%20Issue.pdf#page=18

> [...] soy diet had negative effect on male reproductive system in mice

From what I read, it is not clearly demonstrated that soybean lower testosterone, but I would still be careful about how much I eat.

Comment: So the answer, it seems, depends on whether you are a man or a mouse ;-)